# Is it correct to say " The teacher said that London is the capital of England "?

Tags: tense, phrase-choice, reported-speech

https://znanija.com/task/43770790

On the above address you can see that "The teacher said that London is the capital of England" is mentioned as a correct sentence. Is it grammatically true? If so, why instead of "is" there isn't "was".

Comment: England is still a country and London is still the capital of England. *was* isn't correct.

Comment: but the sentence is "reported speech" isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the information is still true. *The teacher said that London was the capital of England.* would imply that England isn't anymore the capital of England.

Comment: @apaderno or rather that the person reporting the speech *doesn't know* if is still true, or was ever true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facts in reported speech – to backshift or not](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161622/facts-in-reported-speech-to-backshift-or-not)

Comment: However this is a duplicate, and has been asked in one form or another many times before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reported speech, we use the present tense when talking about a fact, general truth, or information that is still true, e.g. Galileo said that the planets **revolve** around the Sun, John said that he **writes** with his left hand, the teacher said that London **is** the capital of England.

[Tense Changes (Reported Speech)](https://www.englishoutsidethebox.com/2017/05/09/tense-changes-reported-speech/)

Comment: I would say that the question case falls under "information that is still true."