# Is "What if I told you I'm a mastermind" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, lyrics

I think the sentence should be "What if I told you I WAS a mastermind?",but this line is from Mastermind written by Taylor Swift. So I'm not so sure about it.

Comment: They amount to the same meaning, Also, song lyrics have special needs that let the writer make exceptions to basic rules. For example, *Ooh, Baby, Baby, Baby* is not good English but can be very catchy as a lyric.

Comment: Voting to close - there's no research here and without that the question boils down to "I think this is wrong, tell me otherwise".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facts in reported speech – to backshift or not](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161622/facts-in-reported-speech-to-backshift-or-not)

Answer (score 2):

You *usually* go back one tense when reporting speech:

> "I'm hungry!", said John.
>
> John said that he **was** hungry.

But you don't always have to do so. In particular, if whatever the reported speech referred to in previous tense is still true, you can keep it in present tense:

> "I'm John's wife", said Jane.
>
> Jane said that she **is/was** John's wife.

In this case, "being a mastermind" is a rather static quality, so keeping the tense is probably okay.

Comment: (as a sidenote, I really hate the "go back one tense" "rule" that's taught in schools all over - instead of learning that rule and trying to figure out exceptions for it, I think it makes more sense to just use the regular rules for tenses, keeping in mind that you're reporting their speech at a different time than when that speech was uttered).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I have seen this pattern from time to time and I am so confused!